# Binding to a usercontrols dependencyproperties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a WPF `UserControl` project named `FormattedTextBox` that contains a `TextBox` and a WPF window project in the same solution.

My user control has two dependency properties registered like this:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =  
    DependencyProperty.Register("Number", 
        typeof(double), 
        typeof(FormattedTextBox), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());  

public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberFormatStringProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("NumberFormatString", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(FormattedTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
```

I make an instance of my usercontrol in the main window. The main window inplements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a property named `MyNumber`. In the XAML of the main window I try to bind to `MyNumber` like this:

```xml
Number="{Binding Path=MyNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The binding doesn't work - I never get into the get or set on the Number property in the user control. Can anybody help?

Comment: run in debug mode... look in output window... see any binding errors?

Answer (score 1):

When a dependency property is set in XAML (or by binding or animation etc.), WPF directly accesses the underlying DependencyObject and DependencyProperty without calling the CLR wrapper. See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx), 
Implications for Custom Dependency Properties.

In order to get notified about changes of the `Number` property, you have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.aspx):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =  
    DependencyProperty.Register("Number", 
        typeof(double), 
        typeof(FormattedTextBox), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(NumberPropertyChanged));

private static void NumberPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = obj as FormattedTextBox;
    ...
}
```